# Calling a function using reflection that has a "params" parameter (MethodBase)

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, mono

I have MethodBases for two functions:

```
public static int Add(params int[] parameters) { /* ... */ }
public static int Add(int a, int b) { /* ... */ }
```

I have a function that calls the MethodBases via a class I made:

```
MethodBase Method;
object Target;
public object call(params object[] input)
{
    return Method.Invoke(Target, input);
}
```

Now if I `AddTwoMethod.call(5, 4);` it works fine.

If I however use `AddMethod.call(5, 4);` it returns:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: parameters do not match signature

Is there any way to make it so that both calls work fine without need for manually putting the arguments in an array for the `params int[]`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could modify your `call` method to detect the params parameter and convert the rest of the input to a new array. That way your method could act pretty much the same as the logic C# applies to the method calling.

Something i quicly constructed for you (be aware that i tested this method in a pretty limited way, so there might be errors still):

```
public object call(params object[] input)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = Method.GetParameters();
    bool hasParams = false;
    if (parameters.Length > 0)
        hasParams = parameters[parameters.Length - 1].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ParamArrayAttribute), false).Length > 0;

    if (hasParams)
    {
        int lastParamPosition = parameters.Length - 1;

        object[] realParams = new object[parameters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lastParamPosition; i++)
            realParams[i] = input[i];

        Type paramsType = parameters[lastParamPosition].ParameterType.GetElementType();
        Array extra = Array.CreateInstance(paramsType, input.Length - lastParamPosition);
        for (int i = 0; i < extra.Length; i++)
            extra.SetValue(input[i + lastParamPosition], i);

        realParams[lastParamPosition] = extra;

        input = realParams;
    }

    return Method.Invoke(Target, input);
}
```

Be aware that i tested this method in a pretty limited way, so there might be errors still.

Comment: Big thanks, Didn't think about getting the custom attributes and testing for params like that!

Comment: @Blam: You can do it the way you were trying with reflection. See my answer for alternate way more similar to what you were trying. Personally I think this solution is way too complicated for what you intend.

Comment: The `call` method can be resolved with a one liner. I find what you propose way too complicated and completely unnecessary. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Supposing we have the following example class:

```
public class Test
{
    public static int Add(int i1, int i2)
    {
        return i1 + i2;
    }

    public static int Add(params int[] ints)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int i in ints)
            sum += i;

        return sum;
    }
}
```

To get the `MethodInfo` objects for each overload of the static `Add` method you should do the following:

```
 MethodInfo Add2Ints = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Add",  new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });
 MethodInfo AddParamsInts = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Add", new Type[] { typeof(int[]) });
```

In order to invoke any of the two methods, symply pass the arguments with the exact type expected by the specific overload you are invoking:

```
 Add2Ints.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1, 2 });
 AddParamsInts.Invoke(null, new object[] { new int[] { 1, 2 } });
```

Note that the following will not work:

```
 AddParamsInts.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1, 2 });
```

because the signature of `AddParmsInt` is really `(int[])` and although the compiler, as a courtesy, *allows* you to call such method as `(int, int)` under the hood what is really happening is that the call is converted for you at the call site to the equivalent `(int[])` call. Via reflection you don't have the compiler's "help" so you need to pass the *exact* argument type defined by the method's signature.

With all that said, your `call` method should be as follows:

```
 public object call(params object[] input)
 {
     return AddParamsInts.Invoke(null /*static*/, new object[] { input.Cast<int>().ToArray() });
 }
```

Note that you can not directly cast a `object[]` array to a `int[]` array: `int[] ints = (int[])input`. Casting *reference* typed *arrays* to *value-type* arrays is not allowed.

Also important to note is that the defined overloads of the `Add` method are useless, as they overlap. Consider only using the `params` overload or, in case you want to guarantee that at least two arguments are needed in order to evaluate an *addition*, overload them the following way:

```
 public int Add(int i1, int i2) { }
 public int Add(int i1, int i2, params int[] args) { }
```

Comment: I understand how the reflection works, I was wondering if it was possible to have a call method that could work as the answer I marked correct has. Like your call method, but not specifically for params int[] functions, the other call method actually works for any function method. Say I create a `Print(String Format, params object[] vars)` function his method can call that properly with `PrintMethod.call("A+B: {0}, A-B: {1}", A+B, A-B);`

Comment: Ok, understood. Hard to gleen that out from you'r original question though ;).

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap the arguments in an array, but the compiler will be confused, so you need to help it a bit:

Eg:

```
AddMethod.call((object) new int[] {5, 4 });
```

Comment: This leads to a System.ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters upon trying to invoke.