# Invoke a method using reflection with the "params" keyword without arguments

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484651/calling-a-function-using-reflection-that-has-a-params-parameter-methodbase) I'm having issues invoking a method that has the "params" keyword. I keep getting TargetParameterCountException  exceptions. "Parameter count mismatch".
The goal is to call this method with no parameters:

```
IList<T> List(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
        //Get generic type
        var entityType = typeof(Applicant).Assembly.GetType(string.Format("Permet.BackEnd.ETL.Domain.Models.{0}", tableName));
        //create service that will receive the generic type
        var constructedIService = typeof(IService<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

        //create the argument for the method that we invoke
        var paramsType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof(object))).MakeArrayType();

        //instantiate the service using Unity (todo: fix singleton)
        var serviceInstance = UnitySingleton.Container.Resolve(constructedIService, "");

        //Invoke the service method "List" by passing it no parameters but telling it the signature to use (it has no overloads)
        //I tried without listing the params since it has no overload but same exception
        //I get exception Parameter count mismatch here
        dynamic data = serviceInstance.GetType().GetMethod("List", new Type[] { paramsType }).Invoke(serviceInstance, new object[] { });
```

Please note that I have tried just passing null and using the overload GetMethod(string name) with exactly the same result.

Comment: You do a lot of work to create the argument object but then you forget to pass it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try invoking it with a single parameter `null` because the C# compiler rewrites the method signature from `method(params object[] parameters)` to `method(object[] parameters)` and also the calls to that method.

```
dynamic data = serviceInstance.GetType().GetMethod("List", new Type[] { paramsType }).Invoke(serviceInstance, new object[] { null });
```

Comment: Yep that was it! Thanks a ton, not sure why I didn't try that since I've tried so many different ways! :)