# Invoke a method using reflection by passing an Expression<Func<T, object>>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-4.0, expression

Following [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777547/invoke-a-method-using-reflection-with-the-params-keyword-without-arguments) it has occured to me that I now need to invoke the same service and the same method by passing an `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to my method. Here is the method definition:

```
IList<T> List(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
```

Here is the code I have right now:

```
  //Get generic type
  var entityRelationType = typeof(Applicant).Assembly.GetType(string.Format("Permet.BackEnd.ETL.Domain.Models.{0}", tableRelation.RelationEntityName));

  //create service that will receive the generic type
  var definitionIService = typeof(IService<>).MakeGenericType(entityRelationType);

  //instantiate the service using Unity (todo: fix singleton)
  var serviceInstance = UnitySingleton.Container.Resolve(definitionIService, "");

  //create the argument for the method that we invoke
  var paramsType =
            typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(entityRelationType, typeof(object))).MakeArrayType();


#region Get Dynamic Data
   ParameterExpression relationParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityRelationType, "");

   //build the parameter that we want to pass to the method (Expression<Func<T, object>>
   var include =
         Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Property(relationParameter,  tableRelation.NaviguationProprietyName),
                    relationParameter
                    );

dynamic datas = constructedIService
                            .GetMethod("List", new Type[] { paramsType }).Invoke(serviceInstance, new object[] { include });
```

The include successfully creates my lambda expression (Param_0 => Param_0.Groupings) which I believed would be my `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. However, since Param_0.Groupings is actually an IList, I get an exception:

> Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Permet.BackEnd.ETL.Domain.Models.CLLI,System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Permet.BackEnd.ETL.Domain.Models.Grouping]]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Permet.BackEnd.ETL.Domain.Models.CLLI,System.Object]][]'.

Which basically means that my `Expression<Func<CLLI, IList<Grouping>>>` cannot be use in my method which expects a `Expression<Func<CLLI, object>>`.

If I actually call my service directly doing:

```
IService<CLLI> clliService = new Service<CLLI>();
clliService.List(clli => clli.Groupings);
```

It works.

How would I go around this issue? Isn't an IList an object?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Expression<T>` is invariant, so even if you have a type `T` which can be assigned to type `U`, that doesn't mean that `Expression<T>` can be assigned to `Expression<U>`. In your case, `T` is `Func<CLI, IList<Grouping>>` and `U` is `Func<CLLI, object>`.

I think the only solution is to create a function to wrap a given expression in an `Expression<Func<T, object>>` which delegates to the inner expression and casts the result to `object`:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> ConvertResult<T, TOut>(Expression<Func<T, TOut>> expr)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var invokeExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr, paramExpr);
    var castExpr = Expression.Convert(invokeExpr, typeof(object));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(castExpr, paramExpr);
}
```

Comment: Following your wrapper, I did a quick test, and it seems that the fact that params is an array and I am passing a single arg is the issue. What you say makes sense, However, I fail to understand why I could call it manually but not with reflection..

Comment: While your wrapper works and I do get to go in the method I invoke, it seems to transform the lambda expression. Please note that this is all using reflection so I transformed your wrapper to receive a LambdaExpression instead. The lambda expression goes from "Param_0 => Param_0.Groupings" to "Param_0 => Convert(Invoke(Param_1 => Param_1.Groupings, Param_0))" which causes issues.