# MethodInfo.Invoke throws exception for variable number of arguments

Tags: c#, reflection

My code is attempting to call multiple methods with a variable number of arguments using MethodInfo.Invoke but the call throws an `ArgumentException`.  What is causing this and how can I fix it?

The methods signature of the methods being called looks like this:

```
private static string MethodBeingCalled(params string[] args) 
{
    //do stuff
    return stringToReturn;
}
```

The line of code that is calling these methods looks like this:

```
string valueReturned = method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "01" }).ToString();
```

This line throws an ArgumentException:

```
Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.
```

When I change MethodBeingCalled to take a fixed list of arguments(ie: `MethodBeingCalled(string arg)`) everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

params is actually a workaround of the compiler. Behind, the real type of the parameter is an array. So when you do this : `method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "01" })`, that cannot work. You need to do this :

```
method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { new string[] {"01"} })
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484831/2045723) . It checks for `ParamArrayAttribute` present and passes values as array.